# How do you optimize less than in where?

Tags: t-sql, query-optimization

Suppose we have a query like below:

```
select top 1 X from dbo.Tab
where SomeDateTime < @P1 and SomeID = @P2
order by SomeDateTime desc
```

What indexes or other techniques do you use to effectively optimize these types of queries?

The table may still have a primary key but on a different column like Id:

```
Id BIGINT IDENTITY PK
X something
SomeDateTime DateTime2
SomeID BIGINT FK to somewhere
```

Suppose there are millions of records for a given SomeDateTime or SomeID - table is "long".
Let's assume that data is read and written with a similar frequency.

For posterity, an article with pictures on the topic:

https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/greater-less-between-tuning-sql-access-filter-predicates

Comment: Create a multicolumn index with `SomeID` first and `SomeDateTime` second

Comment: That was my first thought as well, but i want to confirm it with others. Maybe there is something even more interesting in new versions of MSSQL.

Comment: An index on `( SomeID, SomeDateTime desc )` will make the first match the `top 1` value by `SomeDateTime desc`. Adding `include ( X )` would provide the result shown in your sample `select` directly from the index without needing to access the table row. As with any index, the net performance will depend on how often the index has to be updated vs how often, and effectively, it is used by the query optimizer.

Comment: I think what @HABO said will work for you. If your filters are fixed and are not going to change you can create a partial index as well (but only if your id column or somedate is always going to be the same value)

Comment: I asked just because I got an system to support where hundreds of filtered indexes were created on one table and I was wondering if it wouldn't be better to replace it with one nonfiltered index (data volume does not exceed 1GB).